# What type of form should i use in netbeans?

Tags: java, forms, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm using netbeans and this is my 3rd question unfortunately. I'm creating a database that is used to store images and image information. I've several forms from the netbeans DnD gui that I had created to perfection and would really like to use them some how, however I've realised recently that I can't actually get one variable from one form to the next because they're all isolated from one another.

I've recently accepted that i won't be able to use these forms because they're wrong! I want to know what Java components (Swing forms, AWT forms) to use. I'd Like to start with a login page then instead of creating a new form it switches to a child-like form (or similar) so it can hold variables from the starting login page such as userid. I'll be working on this all night, so don't hesitate to ask questions so I can edit this to make it make more sense :/. THANK YOU

Comment: You have to write event handlers for buttons or menus placed in forms. And process data in these event handlers, create objects of other forms and display them. You can do anything you like.

Comment: Double click on menus or buttons to add event handlers. there you can create objects of other forms and disply them.

Comment: Start by taking a read through [How to create GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans form editor is a tool which helps you with creating user interfaces, what it can't do is produce the functionality you need to make it work, for this you need to actually write some code.

Depending on what you've done, you should be able to write functionality that will allow you to pass to and from your forms, this basic programming.

The basic idea would to create getters and setters that would allow you move information about the various forms.

You should probably start by basing your core UI around something like `JPanel` and build the various elements of your UI around it.

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details.